# How to Convert a Sequence in Java

Tags: java, bluej

I have a DNA text file that has loads of different DNA sequences in it and they all need to be reversed. But I have to use the 'public Sequence reverseComplement' for it and I just don't know what to do.

Comment: Specify the framework / language.

Comment: Hello, Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the tour, visit the help center, and read up on asking good questions. After doing some research and searching for related topics on SO, try it yourself. If you're stuck, post a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example of your attempt and note exactly where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I suggest that you first learn the rules for calculating the reverse complement. Can you describe these rules in English? If I give you a short DNA sequence, what do you do to create the reverse complement? What are the steps required? Use `AGCCGTT` as an example or come up with your own.